# Javascript change background by button

Tags: javascript

so I have code with SHOULD change background color by clicking on button, but the problem is that is don't. I don't get any consol log.

Here is the code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){

var buttonRandomBackGround = document.getElementById("buttonBackground");
var dice = new Audio();
var body = document.body.style.backgroundColor;
var backgroundColor = ["red",
                       "brown"];
dice.src="diceRoll.mp3";


    buttonRandomBackGround.addEventListener("click", test, false)

function test(){

        dice.play();
        setTimeout(waitTillEndSound, 2000);

}
function waitTillEndSound(){
        myNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*1);
        console.log("test");
        body.src = backgroundColor[myNumber];
        console.log(backgroundColor, body);
}

});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please put the code INTO your question.  We should not have to go off StackOverflow.com to answer your question.

Comment: I can't code get broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*1)
```

bit will always result in 0.

Math.random results in a number between 0 and .99999999999999, and multiplying by 1 will not change anything
Math.floor will drop this number to 0 every time.

Try:

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*2)
```

This results in either 0 or 1

To change the background color, do not use the src attribute.

```
document.body.style.background = backgroundColor[myNumber]
```

Comment: Yea I know about that, but it still doesn't change the background

Comment: check my updates at the bottom of the answer. does this help? are you still not seeing any console.log?

Comment: One more, I want use Color hexa but "#000000" doesn't work for example